# Filling combo box with a column from excel sheet C#

Tags: c#, excel, combobox

System.Data.DataRowView is only displayed in the combo box instead of "pmName" from Sheet1 of Project.xlsx. Also, an error appears while adding DisplayMember or ValueMember saying property doesn't exist.

```
public void LoadCustomerCombo3()
{
 try
 {
   using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(constr_xls))
   {
     conn.Open();
     string strSql = "SELECT pmName FROM [Sheet1$]"; 
     OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(new OleDbCommand(strSql, conn));
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     adapter.Fill(ds);
     testCombo.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
     conn.Close();
   }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add items one by one 

    `foreach (var item in xlRange)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
        }`

Comment: Thank you...but didn't help my problem. I already receive the exact number of "System.Data.DataRowView" as the number of items in combo box.

Answer (score 0):

```
        try
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\kanndeva\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\DVC_ProjTool\\Project.xlsx; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 XML;";
            conn.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", conn);
            DataTable ds = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(ds);
            stdCombo.Text = "--Select--";
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                stdCombo.Items.Add(ds.Rows[i]["pmName"]);
            }

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.GetBaseException().ToString(), "Error In Connection");
        }
```

This Worked! Thanks @AKN